# Is A Radial Basis Function Convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

A radial basis function can be represented as

$$
h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i \exp(-\gamma ||x-m_i||^2)
$$

where $w_i$'s are weighs, $\gamma$ is a constant. Is this function convex? As far as I know pretty much any reasonably continous function with hills, bowls can be represented with RBFs of the type above, and couldn't we create a function with many local minima that cannot be convex? But $\exp$ is convex, norm operator is convex, and their linear combination must also be convex.

Comment: Is $x \mapsto e^{-x^2}$ convex???

Comment: I know $e^{-x}$ is convex. Probably $e^{-x^2}$ too.

Comment: It was rhetorical. The Gaussian is **not** convex.

Comment: Right - you could find a line from its tail to the peak that will leave the function.. so not convex. Thanks.